# Downvotes are not shown in recent achievements view

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog

If I get downvotes it is not shown in the recent achievements view.

I think the view should also show negative votes on the fly (over the icon [image] with red background) if I get any.
You can see the downvotes only after you get a positive Reputation.

**If it is not wanted by default/design, it should be configurable, so the user can decide if they want to see it or not.**

Sorry if the description is bad. But I do not know how I can make it better.

I do not think this is a duplicate. Because the other question is only a discussion. The Goal of my question is to think about the design and maybe Change it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Why not? It is also shown in the list

Comment: @RobertLongson If it is not an achivement, is should only listesd in the "achievement list" if i click on the icon

Comment: @RobertLongson the Icon near by the inbox

Comment: Well, it is called **achievements**.. I don't think a downvote is an achievement :P

Comment: @Randy Then click on the Icon and you see that the Headline of the list is also achievements and in the list you find downvotes

Comment: A better idea: not showing reputation gain at all. It's just unnecessary noise. The cardinal rule of a user interface is that you should not show notifications for *unactionable* information. The fact that I passively gained or lost reputation is not actionable. All of these details are visible in your profile if you want to obsessively keep track.

Comment: @CodyGray I think it is not right. I can delete my answer if it is not right and downvoted. So it is actionable in my opinion

Comment: @CodyGray, why unactionable? You see downvotes and try to enhance your post so it looks better and attracts _up_ votes. You see upvotes and again try to enhance your posts for them to get even more upvotes.

Comment: At least, this seems to be a duplicate right now, since an answer saying "it's by design" was accepted. Although, this is tagged [tag:feature-request]... do you want to change the system or simply learn why this behavior occurs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design. There are existing posts out there that go into detail, but the gist of it is that the devs prefer not to show "negative" notifications. Otherwise, your feelings might get hurt and you may come to Meta to complain about downvotes.

[Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements#comment667264_208900)

> The live update feature is there to show you the **good** stuff that happened to your account (rep gains, badges and notifications). – Oded♦ Nov 25 '13 at 14:32

[Why do reputation drops not highlight the Achievements icon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219652/why-do-reputation-drops-not-highlight-the-achievements-icon/219665#219665)

> We want to let you know about good things as soon as they happen - that's what our real-time notifications are for.
>
> Negative reputation changes are... well... negative. So we are not in a hurry to let you know about them.

Comment: Can you link some discussions?

Comment: This rationale is of course extremely dubious. Hiding down votes so people aren't aware of them and don't fix issues with their posts could easily cause mean that by the time it is noticed the post has attracted a greater number of down votes. And I thought the whole point of a rep penalty for down votes was to send a signal to the recipient.

Comment: @MartinSmith I could imagine that people who ask low-quality questions and are hostile towards criticism (mostly low-rep) would respond extremely badly towards downvote notifications, probably acting out in the comment sections or flooding meta with "kill the assholes who downvoted me" rage posts. However, I think it should be tested whether this actually happens, to what extent, and how it scales with the user's rep. Then maybe a privilege could be introduced at some rep level (should be at least 250), to "get rep loss notifications" for users we trust to emotionally survive downvotes.

Comment: Avoiding complaints is a sure fire way to kill your product I hope you'd agree. **Suggestion** - how about requiring some feedback on a down vote as to why the user is down voting? Either text or selections. Something simple. Give an option for no reason and take away more points from their rep for that. There needs to be 2 way accountability and feedback. Edit - I'm even fine with an option for "I didn't like the question" that at least tells me it **IS** out of my control. Not knowing what to do is the frustrating part.

Comment: @JackW327 That suggestion (or a variation of it) is posted here on Meta at least once a week. You might not see them because they always get downvoted, closed and deleted in a short timespan. Short answer is: no, not gonna happen. You can try searching for "downvote reason" or "downvote feedback" to find some of the questions that survived, they explain why it's not a good idea.

Comment: @Stijn, now it becomes strange that this post hasn't been downvoted & deleted yet (and this is good!). Maybe it's finally time to do something about this proposal? Perhaps it could help to mark that post as featured and let people discuss that and make the important decision: whether or not show reputation loss in the 'Achievements' view.

Comment: @JackW327, users _are_ encouraged to leave comments explaining their downvotes, but, to my mind, they do that _very_ rarely as a downvote is as simple as a mouseclick, but a comment takes more time & effort to write.

Comment: @ForceBru,@JackW327  Downvote only with commants is an other discussion. And has nothing to do with this thread. Also "I didn't like the question" is no reason for a downvote in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the opportunity to chime in and thanks for your time.

Comment: And the [Peer Pressure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732) badge?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I had hoped my sarcastic tone would be transferred over text, but to clarify: I don't like how it currently works and would also like to see this implemented. I simply pointed out the previous discussions to explain why it currently works like this. On a slightly related note, I also don't understand that this answer has received downvotes, as if I am able implement this request.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this is by design.

I absolutely agree that such a feature should be added. Why is only positive reputation points change shown? Yes, people may get discouraged if they see reputation points loss, but this will make them care more about how and what they ask and how and what they answer, and this should greatly improve the overall quality of posts and, that's also important, the quality of posts written by new users.

Introducing a switch in the settings that'd allow turning this feature on would be great, in my opinion. It could be off by default, because the users with a lot of reputation points don't probably need to be notified of some slight negative reputation points  change, but it'd be awesome and useful for the newcomers as this'd allow precise reputation points tracking.

While downvotes often come with some comments (this is immediately indicated in the inbox), they appear without any explanation as often, and suddenly discovering a great reputation loss will most certainly make some people hate Stack Overflow as they may not even fully understand *what marvel Stack Overflow really is*.

Comment: Bingo! I got a down vote the other day. I have no clue why. Maybe the person just thought it was a stupid question, okay... There's the vicious cycle. How do you learn unless you ask potentially 'stupid' questions?  **Maybe** it was something I could fix though. As I suggested, some feedback mechanism for down votes would help. Up votes too actually. It's important to know what, exactly, is working too. Thanks for your answer & time.