# I don't see upvotes on Meta SO in the recent achievements list

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, meta, upvotes, achievements-dialog

It is not the duplicate of [Downvotes are not shown in recent achievements view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332621/downvotes-are-not-shown-in-recent-achievements-view) or [Why isn't negative reputation shown in the reputation tab at the top?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289861/why-isnt-negative-reputation-shown-in-the-reputation-tab-at-the-top), for it is not about showing or not the negative info.

If I am publishing a post on Meta SO, I would be glad to see in the Recent Achievements all reactions to that. Not only comments or answers, but also up/downvotes. But I don't see these for the Meta SO question. And I think, for Meta that of/down vote reactions are even more important, for very often we a posting a question on Meta just for knowing the opinion, and the interest of the public in the subject. So, we need to know the whole score.

Notice, that now, if a person does not have enough reputation to know the score up:down by clicking on the balance number, he/she cannot know it at all. On SO itself it is possible by looking into Recent Achievements list, or into Reputation. But not on Meta SO.

It seems as a design bug for me. Or at least, a bug dressed in the feature habit. Ok, let's name it a feature-request.

Comment: Those items in achievements on up/down votes are changes in reputation. There is no reputation involved in voting on meta.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a feature-request, not a bug-report.

Comment: @FirstOne Ok, \*sigh\* let it be a feature-request. But it is not correct. And the fact that many, even majority of you see it so, is merely a sad fact for me. The majority opinion is not a truth yet. And I still believe that design error is an error and not a feature. Maybe, it is not an important error though.

Comment: I just realized this. The description of `achievements-dialog` tag is: _The achievements dropdown is contained in the top-bar and contains recent changes in badges, reputation, and privileges._ It's either a hint as to not showing these notifications there or a need for change - as it's not related to _badges, reputation nor privileges_.

Answer (score 5):

I'll come out and say it, when we [originally created meta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/28/cmon-get-meta/) we took a platform that we clearly stated was *not* a good fit for discussion and asked everyone to go use it for discussion. What could possibly go wrong with that? :)

This, from an *engagement* standpoint, created a lot of deficiencies:

- While we don't have negative reputation, we still have down votes. This can be off-putting to new users that aren't familiar with how meta works.
- It's difficult to 'bump' things that were raised years ago. *It's 2017, can we have table markup in our markdown implementation now?* ***exact duplicate of 2011 request*** (just as an example)
- Even if you've taken the time to look around and get an idea of how things work on meta, it's difficult to know what to search *for* prior to attempting to suggest a feature or open a discussion. But that's okay, much like a fire cracker that failed to detonate, meta only has a 50% chance of blowing your fingers off for messing with it.

Truth be told, I'm not *terribly* upset that we have enough quirky barriers in place to keep folks from just perennially groking meta culture instead of actively participating on the main site, but I do think those barriers are a little *too* thorny at times.

We've also got, from a *practical* standpoint, quite a few deficiencies:

- It's nearly impossible to tell if there was a consensus for any given discussion. *Did this become site policy?* - it can be hard to tell just by searching and reading. It's hard to self-serve here.
- It's hard to direct janitorial tasks at folks that are most capable of accomplishing them. Tag maintenance / removal / renaming requests can sit for *years* sometimes because we failed to let more than a dozen people that actually care about them know there was a discussion going on. Meta isn't tied into the main site very well in a manner where it can tell you *Hey, something about a part of the site you use relatively often is being discussed and that discussion seems to be picking up speed*. We really need that.
- As you note, there's no notification of stuff moving or being finalized in general. Even we (as employees) are still lacking in getting `status-*` tags on things that warrant them.
- There's no formalized poll system (hints at being related to other things listed, but a big enough problem to be listed on its own)

All of this combines together to basically give a `tl;dr;` version:

- Meta did a reasonably good job of getting what we needed at the time, but doesn't scale so well long-term as an engagement platform, or means of enticing people to care more about what goes on behind the scenes.
- Meta has some practical and technical shortcomings that really need to be addressed.

I don't have a timeline here; I don't know how soon we'll be able to say we're going to devote resources to studying things to make sure we understand all of the problems so we can come up with some possible solutions, but we're aware that it lacks luster in places quite a few folks have been conditioned by other platforms to look for it.

So yes, what you describe is a shortcoming (among many), but it's one that we're okay with living with for a while as we look at ways that we can make the whole system better.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that *vote reactions are even more important* - at least not while they are building up.

One vote shouldn't impact so much, but 10..20..50. I find the chronolically advanced POV more important, as pluses and minuses tend either even out or be majorly in favor of one side.

<sup>As yourself said: *we need to know the whole score.*</sup>

**That's the result we* want:** A collective result, not an individual one.

*Note that I'm **not** talking about achievements / badges. The values here are just an example of how multiple numbers weight over singular ones.*

---

<sub>What I think would be *maybe* worth discussing is allowing users with less than 1k reputation to see the vote counts *in meta* and for their questions 
 / answers only.  A matter for another question - if not already discussed. [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318306/why-does-it-take-1000-reputation-to-view-the-vote-count).

(Putting this as sub to avoid discussion in comments)</sub>

Comment: * I _assume_ that's the result we want...

Comment: This is kinda built in already.  At scores of 10, 25, 100 you still earn badges, even on meta.  And badges show up in your notifications.

Comment: Sorry but tbh I don't understand how your comment relates. Maybe it needs elaboration (?) @ryanyuyu

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your post?  You mention that you think collective results are important, and you pointed out some important scoring thresholds (10, 20, 50).  I thought you wanted meta notifications for these scores, so I wrote a reminder that meta badges are already built in for certain scoring thresholds.

Comment: That's **not** what I meant. Those numbers are just there to make my point - about the impact of multiple votes over single ones. I didn't even consider that feature xD @ryanyuyu